# UNITY An object reference is required to access non-static member `Outline.OutlineMode'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an outline when you are near it, but i'm getting all the time the same error.

```
    void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
    var outline = gameObject.AddComponent<Outline>();

    outline.OutlineMode = Outline.Mode.OutlineAll;
    outline.OutlineColor = Color.yellow;
    outline.OutlineWidth = 5f;
    }

}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
    if (Outline.OutlineMode == Outline.Mode.OutlineAll) {
            Debug.Log("test");

    }


}
```

If i press E it works, and if i change it to ontriggerstay works too, but im trying that it only applies one time, because im getting some errors if its on. I have to say that im using an asset, called quick outline

Srry for my very bad english and explanation and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the outline to your object in `Awake()` then set it to disabled.

then enable it in `OnTriggerEnter()` and disable it in `OnTriggerExit()`

this will keep you from making multiple copies, and it will only be active when you are in range of your trigger